# How to group by to auto increment for value which is more than zero by pandas?

Tags: pandas

## data

```
    Group  Value
0     A      2
1     A      4
2     B      1
3     B      3
4     B      0
5     C      0
6     C      5
```

## data2

```
            ts_code    bkb_close
date        
2020-09-30  399106.SZ   0.0000
2020-10-09  399106.SZ   2215.9609
2020-10-12  399106.SZ   2289.3570
2020-10-13  399106.SZ   0.0000
2020-10-14  399106.SZ   0.0000
2020-10-15  399106.SZ   0.0000
2020-10-16  399106.SZ   0.0000
2020-10-19  399106.SZ   0.0000
2020-10-20  399106.SZ   0.0000
2020-10-21  399106.SZ   0.0000
2020-10-22  399106.SZ   0.0000
2020-10-23  399106.SZ   0.0000
2020-10-26  399106.SZ   0.0000
2020-10-27  399106.SZ   2223.9227
2020-10-28  399106.SZ   2239.1080
2020-10-28  399300.SZ   4737.2718
2020-10-29  399106.SZ   2249.5738
2020-10-29  399300.SZ   4772.9198
2020-10-30  399106.SZ   0.0000
2020-10-30  399300.SZ   0.0000
2020-11-02  399300.SZ   4720.8313
2020-11-02  399106.SZ   0.0000
2020-11-03  399106.SZ   2255.0834
2020-11-03  399300.SZ   0.0000
```

## Goal and expected result

Assign column C which is auto increment for each group based on column `Value` . But for value more then zero, the value is nan and the increment should skip zero value.

```
    Group  Value  C 
0     A      2    1
1     A      4    2
2     B      1    1
3     B      3    2
4     B      0    NaN
5     C      0    NaN
6     C      5    1
```

## Try

```
df['C']=df.groupby('Group').transform(lambda x: x[x>0].cumsum()+1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute a mask for the rows with non-0 values, then perform a [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df['C'] = df[df['Value'].ne(0)].groupby('Group').cumcount().add(1)
```

Alternatively, with a [`groupby.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html) on the mask:

```
m = df['Value'].ne(0)
df['C'] = m.groupby(df['Group']).cumsum().where(m)
```

Which is equivalent to a variation of your original attempt:

```
df['C'] = df.groupby('Group').transform(lambda x: (m:=x.gt(0)).cumsum().where(m))
```

Output:

```
  Group  Value    C
0     A      2  1.0
1     A      4  2.0
2     B      1  1.0
3     B      3  2.0
4     B      0  NaN
5     C      0  NaN
6     C      5  1.0
```

Comment: It's strange that it's ok for data1 but data2 returns result that value more than 0 using cumcount methond.

Comment: @Jack not sure what you mean, I tested `df['C'] = df[df['bkb_close'].ne(0)].groupby('ts_code').cumcount().add(1)` on the new dataset and got an incremental counter for the 6 non-zero values. Maybe double check that the mask `df['Value'].ne(0)` is correct, if you have close to zero numbers this might fail. Or use `m = ~np.isclose(df['Value'], 0)` as mask

Comment: 2020-10-09    1
2020-10-12    2
2020-10-27    3
2020-10-28    4
2020-10-29    5
2020-11-03    6

This is my result. It returns 6 rows not 25 rows.

Comment: Of course, just `df[df['bkb_close'].ne(0)].groupby('ts_code').cumcount().add(1)` returns 6 rows, but once assigned to the original dataframe as new column, the missing ones will be NaN. If you don't want to assign then use the other methods (or reindex)

Comment: sorry, I update data2. if using df[df['bkb_close'].ne(0)].groupby('ts_code').cumcount().add(1), it will raise ValueError: cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels

Comment: @Jack I see, this is because you have duplicated indices in the index. This solution only works with unique indices, you should use one of the other two ;)

Comment: cumsum method works.